# Is there a keyboard for Android designed for coding?

Tags: android, c++, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Is there a GBoard or Samsung keyboard that can be downloaded onto a Android device (like a Samsung S10) that makes it easier for coding (C++), ie: includes +, =, /, etc in a more accessible place?

Answer (score 5):

There's [Hackers Keyboard](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard/) (also available [at Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard)), but it wasn't updated for quite a while. It gives you easy access to everything you need for programming or "console stuff":

[image] [image]
<sup>(click screenshots for larger variants)</sup>

Similar to that but also long time not updated is [BeHe keyboard](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.vlath.keyboard/) ([Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vlath.keyboard)):

[image] [image] [image]

Quite up-do-date and also targeted at developers is [Unexpected Keyboard](https://f-droid.org/packages/juloo.keyboard2/) ([Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=juloo.keyboard2)):

[image] [image]

While none of them are made by Google or Samsung, they're all open source and should meet your requirements quite well: make coding easier by having the relevant keys in easy reach. Take your pick and enjoy!

Comment: I use the Hacker's Keyboard and have no complaints about it.

Comment: I just downloaded unexpected keyboard, and it's great so far